# Morphlines date format exception

Tags: solr, hbase, cloudera, morphline

I Want to convert field to date format like that:

```
{ 
    convertTimestamp {
        field : document_date
        inputFormats : ["yyyy-MM-dd"]
        inputTimezone : UTC
        outputFormat : "yyyy"
        outputTimezone : UTC
}
```

The input format is `yyyy-MM-dd` and I want to output only year's part `yyyy`.

But When I run it - I've got an Exception: 
`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date String:'1992-06-04'`.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832338) that morphline requires obligatory format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` but you can find on morphline's [Github](https://github.com/kite-sdk/kite/blob/master/kite-morphlines/kite-morphlines-core/src/main/java/org/kitesdk/morphline/stdlib/ConvertTimestampBuilder.java) that TimestampBuilder has default format date like:

```
DEFAULT_DATE_FORMATS.add("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Exception remains even if i change output format to `yyyy-MM-dd`. It disappears only when I add constant sufix like: `T23:59:59Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about what `Morphline's` default format is . I have worked for quite a sometime with Solr , and the only format it supports is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`. Look below for a very descriptive documentation about it from Solr's documentation webpage only .[image]

Also , the link of the `Morphline's Github Code` states in its last comments this thing `A suite of default date formats that can be parsed,`and thus transformed to the **Solr specific format** . Find below image for reference
[image]

So basically, it also adheres to the Standard Solr Format , and ultimately such formats just make good candidates to be transformed into Solr's format. Hope this helps :) .